# How to decompress data stored in HDF5 file compressed with zstd?

Tags: compression, python-3.6, hdf5, h5py, zstd

I faced some problems with decompression in zstd case. I have hdf5-format files, that was compressed in the following way:

```
import h5py as h5
import hdf5plugin
import sys
import os
filefrom = sys.argv[1] 
h5path  = sys.argv[2]
f = h5.File(filefrom,'r')
data = f[h5path]
shape_data = data.shape[1:]
num = data.shape[0]
initShape = (1,) + shape_data
maxShape = (num,) + shape_data
f_zstd = h5.File(filefrom.split('.')[0]+'_zstd.h5','w')
d_zstd = f_zstd.create_dataset(path_to_data, initShape, maxshape=maxShape, dtype=np.int32, chunks=initShape, **hdf5plugin.Zstd())
d_zstd[0,] = data[0,]
for i in range(num):
    d_zstd.resize((i+1,) + shape_data)
    d_zstd[i,] = data[i,]
f_zstd.close()
f.close()
```

So it compressed without any errors, but then when I try to look into the data with `h5ls` or `h5dump` it prints me out that data can't be printed, and no another way to look inside the file like reading in python3 (3.6) with h5py this compressed data is unsuccessful. I also tried `h5repack` (`h5repack -i compressed_file.h5 -o out_file.h5 --filter=var:NONE`) or the following piece of code:

```
import zstandard
import pathlib
import os

def decompress_zstandard_to_folder(input_file):
    input_file = pathlib.Path(input_file)
    destination_dir = os.path.dirname(input_file)
    with open(input_file, 'rb') as compressed:
        decomp = zstandard.ZstdDecompressor()
        output_path = pathlib.Path(destination_dir) / input_file.stem
        with open(output_path, 'wb') as destination:
            decomp.copy_stream(compressed, destination)
```

nothing succeed. In situation with `h5repack` no warnings or errors appeared, with the last piece of code I got this `zstd.ZstdError: zstd decompressor error: Unknown frame descriptor`, so as I got it means that compressed data doesn't have the appropriete headers.

I use `python 3.6.7`, `hdf5 1.10.5`. So I'm a bit confused and don't have any idea how to overcome this issue.

Will be happy for any ideas/advice!

Comment: can you  open them with HDFView?

Comment: no, but we found the problem)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple test to validate zstd compression behavior with a simple dataset (NumPy array of int32). I can open the HDF5 file with h5py and read the dataset. (Note: I could not open with HDFView and h5repack only reports shape and type attributes, not the data.)

I suspect an undetected error in another part of your code. Have you tested your code logic without zstd compression? If not, I suggest you start there.

**Code to Write example file:**

```
import h5py as h5
import hdf5plugin
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(1_000).reshape(100,10)

with h5.File('test_zstd.h5','w') as f_zstd:
    d_zstd = f_zstd.create_dataset('zstd_data', data=data, **hdf5plugin.Zstd())
```

**Code to Read example file:**

```
import h5py as h5
import hdf5plugin  ## Note: plugin required to read

with h5.File('test_zstd.h5','r') as f_zstd:
    d_zstd = f_zstd['zstd_data']
    print(d_zstd.shape, d_zstd.dtype)
    print(d_zstd[0,:])
    print(d_zstd[-1,:])
```

**Output from above:**

```
(100, 10) int32
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[990 991 992 993 994 995 996 997 998 999]
```

**More on HDF5 and compression:**
To use HDF5 utilities (like h5repack) to read a compressed file, the HDF5 installation needs the appropriate compression filter. Some are standard, many (including xstandard), require you to install a third party filter. Links to available plugins are here: [HDF5 Registered Filter Plugins](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/support/Registered+Filter+Plugins)

You can verify the compression filter with h5dump by adding the `-pH` flag, like this:

```
E:\SO_68526704>h5dump -pH test_zstd.h5
HDF5 "test_zstd.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "zstd_data" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I32LE
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 100, 10 ) / ( 100, 10 ) }
      STORAGE_LAYOUT {
         CHUNKED ( 100, 10 )
         SIZE 1905 (2.100:1 COMPRESSION)
      }
      FILTERS {
         USER_DEFINED_FILTER {
            FILTER_ID 32015
            COMMENT Zstandard compression: http://www.zstd.net
         }
      }
      FILLVALUE {
         FILL_TIME H5D_FILL_TIME_ALLOC
         VALUE  H5D_FILL_VALUE_DEFAULT
      }
      ALLOCATION_TIME {
         H5D_ALLOC_TIME_INCR
      }
   }
}
}
```

Comment: o thanks, I tried your piece of code and try to look on data with h5ls and got ```H5tools-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5:tools (1.10.5) thread 0:
  #000: h5tools_dump.c line 1632 in h5tools_dump_simple_dset(): H5Dread failed
    major: Failure in tools library
    minor: error in function
```
can you specify the hdf5 version that you work with? 
I tested my piece of code with other compression and it worked. But crashed with zstd. And i'm a bit confused

Comment: also i tried to work with hdf5 1.12.0 and use h5ls -d for looking inside the data and again got ```Unable to print data.```

Comment: On the Python side, I am using conda distribution versions : `Python 3.8.3`, `h5py 3.3.0` (built with `hdf5 1.10.6`) and `hdf5plugin 3.1.1` on Windows. Try: `h5dump -pH test_zstd.h5`? Output from `h5ls test_zstd.h5`: is `zstd_data  Dataset {100, 10}`. I can also open with HDFView. I don't have the zstd third party plugin installed, so can't view the data with `h5dump` or `HDFView`. `h5dump --version` returns `h5dump: Version 1.10.6` and the same for `h5ls`.

Comment: Ok, i'll try this, thanks! it is not the first time when you help me :) thanks a lot!

Comment: but i'm still confused why i can't open ```test_zstd.h5``` next time like next day using this:
```with h5.File('test_zstd.h5','r') as f_zstd:
    d_zstd = f_zstd['zstd_data']
    print(d_zstd.shape, d_zstd.dtype)
    print(d_zstd[0,:])
    print(d_zstd[-1,:])```

Comment: Did you have `import hdf5plugin` in your code to read the file? You need it to read the compressed data. My test works when I include the package. and it fails when I don't include it.